# Why are cardlayout keys passed as Objects?

Tags: java, swing, enums, cardlayout

`java.awt.CardLayout.addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints)`

"The object specified by constraints must be a string" from the docs.oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).

So Why does this method take an object as argument if the object must be a string? The question is nagging me because it leads me to hope that there is an easy way to use enums as keys for a cardlayout.

```
public class MainWindow extends JPanel {

private CardLayout cards = new CardLayout();

public MainWindow() {
    setLayout(cards);
    cards.addLayoutComponent(new FirstComp(), MyEnum.LONG_ANNOYING_NAME_ONE);
    cards.addLayoutComponent(new SecondComp(), MyEnum.LONG_ANNOYING_NAME_TWO);
    cards.addLayoutComponent(new ThirdComp(), MyEnum.LONG_ANNOYING_NAME_THREE);
    /**
     * notice no .toString() call on enums. Is there a way to define my
     * enum class so that this functionality is possible?
     **/
}

public void showMethod(MyEnum show) {
    cards.show(this, MyEnum);
}
}
```

---

```
public enum MyEnum {

    LONG_ANNOYING_NAME_ONE, LONG_ANNOYING_NAME_TWO, LONG_ANNOYING_NAME_THREE

}
```

Answer (score 1):

LayoutManager2 defines addLayoutComponent(Component, Object).  The second argument is Object because different layout managers can support different kinds of constraints.  CardLayout implements LayoutManager2 and as such it must implement the method as defined.

Answer (score 1):

As the javadoc states the constraints Object must be a String.

However, nothing is stopping you from extending the CardLayout, and re-implementing the method the way you wish:

```
public class MyCardLayout extends CardLayout {

    @overrive
    public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {

       if  (constraints != null) {
         super.addLayoutComponent(comp, constraints.toString());
       } else {
         super.addLayoutComponent(comp, constraints);
       }
    }
}
```